# iterate through all features and CalculateField with function

Tags: arcpy, convert

So I have a gdb, and the feature class I'm working on has a field that is formatted in html for ArcGISOnline. This is great if I'm only viewing the data online. What I'm trying to do is copy that attribute data to a new field and then convert the data from html. There is a great tool that does this well, html2text.

My question is: How do I go about getting the tool to play nice with arcpy?

Here's where I am right now and it's not converting the value for me

```
import html2text, arcpy
from arcpy import env
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/Workspace/Data_National/RGOV/temp/20170330_RGOV.gdb/"
Rgdb = "C:/Workspace/Data_National/RGOV/temp/20170330_RGOV.gdb"
FFA = Rgdb + "/RSites/Facapp"

arcpy.AddField_management(FFA, "FFA", "TEXT", "", "", "8000")
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(FFA, "FACILITYDESCRIPTION") as cursor:
    for htmlformat, in cursor:
        Expression = html2text.html2text(htmlformat)
        arcpy.CalculateField_management(FFA, "FFA", html2text.html2text('!FACILITYDESCRIPTION!'), "PYTHON_9.3", Expression)
```

Any pointers on where I'm going wrong?
I also tried throwing a

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management(FFA, "FFA", html2text.html2text('!FACILITYDESCRIPTION!'), "PYTHON_9.3")
```

but it didn't work...

When I used the CalculateField tool, the script runs through with no errors, but keeps the html formatting.

When I try it with the SearchCursor section of the script I get an error of "data = data.replace("/' + 'script)", "(/ignore)")

[image: error message]

Comment: Is the FACILITYDESCRIPTION field for *every* record formatted as HTML?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to give the error message text in full

Comment: Yes @Fezter every value is formatted in HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the tricky parts of using CalculateField in a script. You are importing `html2text` into the script but the field calculator does not know it is imported as it starts a new internal scripting session. As far as I can see you are already calculating value for this additional field with `Expression` variable and there is nothing inhibiting you to use it directly, e.g., `arcpy.CalculateField_management(FFA, "FFA", Expression, "PYTHON_9.3")`. However it will recalculate this column with every iteration, which is a terrible practice. I recommend you to use the ArcMap's field calculator directly as shown below:

1. In ArcMap, create a new text field, as you defined for FFA
2. Calculate this field with the code block and expression with PYTHON below:

Pre-logic script code: `import html2text`

(Field to calculate) FFA=: `html2text.html2text(!FACILITYDESCRIPTION!) if !FFA! else ""`

More clearly, see below the snapshot:

[image]

Comment: his method runs through fine with no errors, but the new field values are still in html format. Maybe I didn't script it correctly? This is what I tried `Expression = html2text.html2text("!FACILITYDESCRIPTION!") `   `arcpy.CalculateField_management(FFA, "FFA", Expression, "PYTHON_9.3")`  I tried single and double quotes around `!FACILITYDESCRIPTION!` both methods yielded the same results

Comment: Most probably the quotation mark in the expression is the problem which cause html2text to get everything as string literal. Please be aware, this is not a scripting solution but simple field calculator operation. I have also updated the expression to avoid NULL values to throw any exception.

Comment: ok, using this method in script works, but for some reason in ArcMap, only the first 170 characters are displayed, but on ArcGISOnline all is well. Here is the script I used `import arcpy, html2text     Expression = "html2text.html2text(!FACILITYDESCRIPTION!)"
arcpy.CalculateField_management(FFA, "FFA", Expression, "PYTHON_9.3")`

Comment: I think this is exactly the same problem that you directed to @Midavalo, special  character issue at a specific position in the string, most probably a line break/feed. There are options in `html2text` module as explained in [the documentation](https://github.com/Alir3z4/html2text/blob/master/docs/usage.md#using-options). I cannot test it right now but by first creating a parser after `import html2text` (e.g., `text_maker = html2text.HTML2Text()`) and then setting escape parameter, `text_maker.escape_snob = True`, you may overcome this issue.

Comment: But in this case your (Field to calculate) `FFA=` should be `text_maker(!FACILITYDESCRIPTION!) if !FFA! else ""`

Comment: Or first try `html2text.html2text(repr(!FACILITYDESCRIPTION!)) if !FFA! else ""`

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using Calculate Field within a Search Cursor, why not update your fields with an Update Cursor?

```
import html2text, arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/Workspace/Data_National/RGOV/temp/20170330_RGOV.gdb/"
Rgdb = "C:/Workspace/Data_National/RGOV/temp/20170330_RGOV.gdb"
FFA = Rgdb + "/RSites/Facapp"

arcpy.AddField_management(FFA, "FFA", "TEXT", "", "", "8000")

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(FFA, ["FACILITYDESCRIPTION", "FFA"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0]:
            row[1] = html2text.html2text(row[0])
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: I'm still getting an error, shown above, with this method.

Comment: I checked the table again, and noticed that there were several <null> values. I added text in there and this method work. Thanks!

Comment: @morgan I have updated my answer to check that the value in `FACILITYDESCRIPTION` isn't `NULL`.  If it is then it'll skip it, if it has a value then it will proceed.

Comment: I let this take a backseat for a while and tried the script again. I noticed that for some reason the script fixes the first 340 characters, and drops all the rest of the value when this method is used.

Comment: @morgan What happens if you (separate to this script) set a variable containing one of your values that's failing, then use the `html2text` into another variable.  Does this output the complete expected string, or is this also only the first 340 characters?

Comment: It only does the first 340 characters even when I try that

Comment: @morgan Then the issue lies with `html2text`.  Is there a specific character (or type of character) that occurs at around 340?

Comment: It turned to just be an invisible line break, so it only looked like the values were cut off

Comment: @morgan that could possibly also be controlled using python